# Acceso a la propiedad del objecto e con una variable

Tags: javascript, html

He creado una funcion para agregar opciones a un elemento select llamada "rellenaSelect" .
Las opciones estan dentro de un array.

El contenido del array es el siguiente:

```
var arr = "[ { "ARGUMENTO": "2", "DESCRIPCION": "Elemento2" } , 
             { "ARGUMENTO": "1", "DESCRIPCION": "Elemento1" } ]";
```

La llamada a la funcion es la siguiente:

```
rellenaSelect("Seleccion1", arr, "ARGUMENTO", "DESCRIPCION");
```

El nombre del atributo de los elementos que contiene el array puede ser variable. Es decir en vez de "ARG" o "DESC" se pueden llamar "ARGUMENTO" y "DESCRIPCION".

¿ Como puedo referenciar con una variable esto ? Lo he intentado de esta manera pero no queda referenciado bien el argumento del objeto

```
function rellenaSelect( idSelect, items, arg, desc )
{
   var select = document.getElementById(idSelect);
   items.forEach( function (e) {
   {
      var opt = document.createElement('option');
      opt.Value = e. "" + "arg";
      opt.innerHTML = e."" + "desc";
      select.appendChild(opt);
   });
}
```

Comment: Por las dudas no veas la relación entre tu pregunta y la otra, la sintaxis correcta es `opt.value = e[arg];` (_acceder a la propiedad del objecto `e` cuyo nombre es igual a la cadena en la variable `arg`_)

Comment: @Marcos gracias por lar respuesta correcta.